# Deploy spring boot to websphere 8.5.5.5

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, websphere-8

I am trying to build a spring boot project for websphere using jpa, hibernate, jersey.

Once I know that websphere is only support JPA 2.0, I found this article([Halo, I am article](http://naruraghavan.github.io/deploying-spring-boot-applications-in-ibm-websphere-application-server/)) and try to follow it. However it seems not work to me. Throwing Exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl incompatible with javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:77)
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:137)
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:46)
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1396)
>       ... 137 more

My pom.xml is set below
`
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.2.7.RELEASE

```
<properties>
    <start-class>com.jersey.Application</start-class>
    <jersey-version>2.7</jersey-version>
    <jackson-version>2.4.3</jackson-version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End Spring -->

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Jackson -->

    <!-- Guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Guava -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>`
```

I would like to know is there any missing for deploying spring boot to websphere?

**Update**

What I have done 
1) add hibernate version and downgrade it to 4.2.15:Final
2) set parent last to the class loader

I would like to know is there any complete sample that can deploy to websphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no missing dependency, there is one too much. You shouldn't include the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api, because WebSphere already provides the JPA API classes, so if you set the scope to provided for that dependency, it should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This applies to all Java EE APIs, which are provided by the container. They shouldn't be included in your deployment.

Another point, which could simplify your pom.xml: To change the Hibernate version, Spring Boot provides a property to manage the versions explicitly. Just add the following to your properties tag:

```
<hibernate.version>4.2.15.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Then you can remove the exclusion tags with hibernate and the two dependencies to hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The same exception throws after I set jpa2.0 to provide or just delete it

Comment: The java.lang.ClassCastException still throw. Is there any coding I need to do or config I am missing?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: This problem is solve, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api should set to provided so that no jpa api in the application. Dunni, Thanks!